# get Metadata from Url using MetadataExtractor in C#

Tags: c#, metadata-extractor

I have used following code but I can't get any response from that
I have faced exception from this like 
'The given path's format is not supported.'

```
else if (Path.GetExtension(blobFilePath).ToLower() == ".jpg"  ||
         Path.GetExtension(blobFilePath).ToLower() == ".jpeg" ||
         Path.GetExtension(blobFilePath).ToLower() == ".gif"  || 
         Path.GetExtension(blobFilePath).ToLower() == ".png")
{
    filepath = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
}

IEnumerable<MetadataExtractor.Directory> directories =
    ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(filepath.ToString());
```

Can you please help me out from this ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value in this variable blobFilePath ?

Comment: blobfilePath = "AllJobs/dberror.PNG"   and blob.URI.absoluteURI like "https://loudshark.blob.core.windows.net/nordiccompanyinc/AllJobs/dberror.PNG"

Comment: are you getting error in else if block or while reading metadata from the image file ?

Comment: no bro... I am getting error while executing following part of the code IEnumerable<MetadataExtractor.Directory> directories =
    ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(filepath.ToString()); while it is reading metadata from particular file path but when this file can be jpg or png then filepath should be a URL so this way it would be fired exception like "The given filepath's format is not suppoted to read metadata"

Comment: Can you please share the source details / reference details for the MetadataExtractor.Directory ?

Answer (score 2):

The overload of `ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata` you're using expects a file system path. Using a URL won't work.

Instead, you must open the network stream and pass it. Assuming your URL uses HTTP or HTTPS, something like this should do it:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
using (var content = response.Content)
using (var stream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
    // NOTE passing a stream here, not a string
    var directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(stream);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: bro... It's not working stop executing the code from the second line of above code using(var response = await client.getAsync(url))

Comment: I am using "https://loudshark.blob.core.windows.net/nordiccompanyinc/AllJobs/101017 - jsmin/2C3A0481.MOV" this azure storage url it give me not any error but stop execution and hang the application. I thought it's getting very long time to get response from this url